# DataGridView column aligment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I use Visual-Studio-2012. Basically I have 5 column DataGridView with product,quantity,price,+,- and I would like to align all text of products I put into my basket as MiddleCentered except actual Product description (it stays MiddleLeft as default).

I can change aligment via RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle, but I can't choose which columns I would like to align and it makes all of them MiddleCentered.

Is there any way to do so? I was trying to search on the NET, but didn't find anything clear. Help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted your code, here is a way to aligning the text,

dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;

Give a try and if you still not able to align the text, please post your code.

Comment: Didn't worked. I need all text to be MiddleCenter (except product column, not exact column but what's under him - all products). What part of my code do you need? I have private void dataGridView1_CellClick, it's the only set for this. Other was set on button that transfers products into DataGridView.

Answer (score -1):

Holly spirit, I found the answer. I can change it via Edit Columns, selecting column and changing aligment. How stupid do I feel now. Damn...Sorry to bother guys.